# WCF config error in Azure: Unrecognized attribute 'protectTokens'. Works fine in on-premises .NET 4 environment

Tags: .net, azure, .net-4.0, wcf-configuration

Our .Net 4 component accesses a third-party web service via a WCF client proxy. The WSDL for the third-party web service contains the Protect Tokens security policy:

```
<sp:ProtectTokens />
```

Accordingly, the custom binding configuration generated by Visual Studio 2013 contains:

```
protectTokens="true"
```

We've been using this for some weeks in our on-premises environment without any issues. However, on updating our Azure environment with this version of the app, we find it throws an exception:

```
Unrecognized attribute 'protectTokens'.
Note that attribute names are case-sensitive
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.securityelementbase.protecttokens%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) seems conflicted on what .NET version supports protectTokens. The linked page is headed .NET 4.6 and 4.5, but its footer states "Available since 3.0". Regardless, the app is built for 4.0 and as I said, gives no error in the on-premises environment.

What is causing the error in Azure? This is OS Family 2 (2008R2).

Comment: have you tested my proposed answer?

Comment: @JuanK I see I must now be more blunt than in my earlier comment:your response does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

**SecurityElementBase.ProtectTokens Property** if only available in framework  >= 4.5

You can check ***ProtectTokens*** documentation here

[Full SecurityElementBase class properties for framework 4.5 , 4.6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.securityelementbase(v=vs.110).aspx) (you can get **ProtectTokens** property)

[Full SecurityElementBase class properties for framework 4.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.securityelementbase(v=vs.100).aspx) (no such **ProtectTokens** property)

### Whole Story

msdn documentation bug.

I was digging into IL in the assemblies **SecurityElementBase.dll** for .net 4 and 4.5. and guess what indeed there's no `ProtectTokens` Property in .Net < 4.5 .

1. **.Net 4**: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.ServiceModel.dll`
2. **.Net 4.5**: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.dll`

You can verify it even more easily using VS2015 object explorer.

#### System.ServiceModel.dll .NetFX 4

[image: System.ServiceModel.dll .net 4]

#### System.ServiceModel.dll .NetFX 4.5

[image: System.ServiceModel.dll .net 4.5]]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the whole story though. As I said, MSDN gives conflicting information. And the idea that protectTokens is not supported in  .NET Framework 4 itself conflicts with the fact that protectTokens was generated, and works in the on-premises environment, in an app that specifically targets .NET Framework 4.

Comment: @RegEdit I have added more details verifying directly into assemblies.

Comment: This does not answer the question.